# What is the best way to store pageviews in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table "news" where I store "id","title","description". I would like to store pageviews and later use it to rank pages according to popularity.
What is the best way to do it? I've heard a lot of people complain about MySQL freezing due to high traffic. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Don't worry. At that volume of traffic, you'll easily be generating enough revenue to employ a DBA full time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple counter would work, something like: update news set page_views=page_views+1 where id=xxxx

MySQL drives a lot of very large sites....

Comment: Should I set the $page_views to autoincrement or should I set the value default to 0 in each case?

Comment: Don't use autoincrement.  Set it to default to 0.  Then, setup your site so that it runs the update statement above each time a viewer access a news story (where xxxx is the unique id for that news story).